# When constructing a selector I am getting an error if space included

Tags: javascript, jquery

When building a selector I want to have a space to indicate that a class is to be found within an element defined by two classes. I am sure that I have used this syntax elsewhere.

But on this occasion I get:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " [Break On This Error] throw new Error( "
>   Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );

Here is the selector:

```
tag = $(".m_3.current_Status .smoothie_Text").prop("tagName");
```

If I remove the space before .smoothie_Text the syntax error disappears but obviously tag is undefined as it cannot be found.

**EDIT**

```
<td class="m_1 current_Status" style="background-color: rgb(255, 127, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<div class="smoothie hasSVG">
<input class="smoothie_Text" type="hidden" value="Super Power">
<svg version="1.1" stroke-width="0.501" stroke-linejoin="bevel" fill-rule="evenodd" overflow="visible" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 236.25 225">
</div>
</td>
```

**EDIT - Solution (#2 shortened) **

Note - in the end I did not use the comma separated approach. I cannot be certain why previous attempt to in groups of classes separated by a space failed, but, I suspect that the select submitted was enclosed in quotes.

```
$(".smoothie").on("mouseover", function(event) {

    var containerElements = $(event.target).parentsUntil($("tr").parent())
         .map(function () { 
             return this.className; 
         })
         .get().join(",");

    containerArray = containerElements.split(",");
    row_Class = containerArray.pop();
    row_Classes = row_Class.split(" ");
    container_Class = containerArray.pop();
    container_Classes = container_Class.split(" ");

    var offset = $(event.target).offset();

    value = $("." + row_Classes[0] + "." + row_Classes[1] + " ." + container_Classes[0] + "." + container_Classes[1] + " .smoothie_Text").attr("value");

    $("#flavour_Text").html("<a>" + value + "</a>");
    $("#flavour_Text").css("top", offset.top);
    $("#flavour_Text").css("left", offset.left);
    $("#flavour_Text").css("width", (value.length * 0.6) + "em")
    $("#flavour_Text").css("display","block");

    // this dsiplays all. Needs refinement

}).svg({loadURL: '../_public/_icons/smoothie.svg'});   

$(".smoothie").on("mouseout", function(event) {
    $("#flavour_Text").html("");
    $("#flavour_Text").css("display","none");
}).svg({loadURL: '../_public/_icons/smoothie.svg'});
```

Comment: can you show your HTML markup?

Comment: HTML markup wouldn't cause a *SyntaxError*. We need to see a working example of the JavaScript code.

Comment: Not that this answers your question, but you can try this: `tag = $(".smoothie_Text", ".m_3.current_Status").prop("tagName");`

Comment: This error is thrown by [Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/66ecdfec4f79c3fac9a24a2bf9de7bb0fc48ec3b/sizzle.js#L1050). The selector you're building is not what you're expecting, and not what you're showing in the question. Show your *actual* code.

Comment: I have cut a pasted the html as reported in the console. I had no idea I could comma separate the class or group of classes or id in the way I will test it in a minute.

Comment: The selector is valid: http://jsfiddle.net/J3VR3/ Do you have some more code?

Comment: @codepuppy: That's an optional context argument. There's still something wrong though. You should post your actual JavaScript code. You're leaving something out.

Comment: @PinnyM it worked!! Fantastic. I confess I have spent several hours looking at the this. I am still not sure why the difference except that this is wrapped inside an svg event -     $(".smoothie").on("mouseover", function(event) {.....}).svg({loadURL: '../_public/_icons/smoothie.svg'}); But can't see why that would alter the selector.

Comment: @codepuppy: You were doing something else wrong that isn't shown in the question. It could be that you had some invalid invisible character in your selector string. This happens sometimes if you copy/paste code from jsFiddle. You should try to resolve the actual issue you asked about, which is the SyntaxError.

Comment: @user1689607 No no cut and paste. I originally constructed the selector using concatenated strings. When this failed I typed out the selector in full and it still failed. I wondered if it is because I am using jquery.svg.min.js and jquery.svgdom.min.js to make the svg "clickable" does this in some way alter the selector. I dropped Keith Wood a line but have had no reply yet. In the meantime using the coma separated syntax (new to me) is good. The  issue has been how to traverse the dom when svg used as next/prev/nextUntil/parentUntil not working. I should now have a work around.

Comment: Your piece of code works well. There's a problem somewhere outside. You need to seek for some throw Error code. **unrecognized expression: " + msg** is a clue.

Comment: @codepuppy: As I showed in the link above, the error comes from Sizzle. You are not representing whatever actually gave you the error.

Comment: @user1689607 yes I entirely understand that you are showing me the original of the console error message. WHat I am not sure that I understand is how sizzle came to incorporate in the jquery download. I don't think that I explicitly asked for it. I need to follow that up. Perhaps jquery.svg incorporates it. In the meantime I have edited the question. This code works for me.

Comment: @codepuppy: [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com) is the selector engine that jQuery uses. It's included in the jQuery download, and it's what is throwing the syntax error.

Comment: @IHateLazy Ok thank you for that. I am still having problems.

Comment: @user1689607  - OK I have got it work WITH a space in the selector betweebn the groups of classes. I think that the actual select submitted was enclosed in quotes creating the syntax error.

Comment: @codepuppy: That would make sense. Having odd syntax like misplaced quotation marks in the selector would most certainly cause errors of this nature. *(I changed my user name. I'm the @user1689607)*